# Reviewing a website 

Tags: web

Hi
I'm looking for a tool (free/paid) like a program that help me in reviewing my website style and interface such as explain the content of the home page (footer, header ..... ) taking snapshots and write comment on them ... I know this can be done using (print screen) and the MS paint but I need a more professional tool to use .

thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need a more professional tool? What features are you looking for that Paint does not offer? Tried photoshop?

Comment: I'm making an official paper about the website so Im looking for a pro tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand well, but [conceptshare](http://www.conceptshare.com/) may be the tool you looking for.

Comment: @ lonut this a great tool but I want an offline tool

Comment: in a world that strive to go in the cloud you want to go offline? :D

Answer (score 0):

There's a firefox extension called [Screengrab](http://www.screengrab.org/) that can capture an entire page. You could add annotations to that quite easily in a DTP tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the type of review you're looking for.

If you want to have people using the website and giving you their feedback in terms of navigation, layout, design and content, you can use a www.usertesting.com services.

They'll enroll users to test out the website and them give you a URl to review a video/audio recording of each user test. It's a great way to validate your website.

Hope this is what you were looking for...